# Fit a three-pulse sequence

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, nonlinear, piecewise

I am wondering how to properly fit the three-pulse sequence shown below.[image: Three-pulse sequence]

I have tried a method which is fitting the three pulses with three polynominal functions seperately and then finding the x-axis values where y==0. Afterwards, I can construct a piecewise function which contains the three polynominal functions with the boundary values same as the obtained x-axis values where y==0. The regime out of the boundary values is set to be 0. The fitting actually looks not too bad, as shown below.[image: Fitted Three-pulse sequence]

However, as you may see, due to the inaccuracy of the set boundary values (the obtained x-axis values at y==0 are always approximate values), there are gaps such as at x=0.73 or x=1.5. Since I need to use this three-pulse sequence as a known function for NDSolve in the next stage, the gaps seem can cause errors like singularity or stiff system.

May I ask is there any better way to fit the three-pulse sequence continuously? The dataset can be found in the attached link.[dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j61hp0rexvxnr5o/3350V_dataset_pump_ms.xlsx?dl=0)

The fitting procedure what I have used is shown below:

```
PickedPumpData = Take[PumpData, {1, 49}];(*Data Pickup*)
RealPumpCurve = ListPlot[PickedPumpData, PlotRange -> All]
CurveFit = 6;
PumpFit[t_] = Fit[PickedPumpData, Table[t^i, {i, 1, CurveFit}], t]
SimulatedPumpCurve = Plot[PumpFit[t], {t, 0, 0.23}]
Solve[PumpFit[t] == 0, t]
Pumpcurve1[t_] := If[t > 0.2275646211603083` || t < 0, 0, PumpFit[t]]

PickedPumpData2 = Take[PumpData, {148, 191}];(*Data Pickup*)
RealPumpCurve2 = ListPlot[PickedPumpData2, PlotRange -> All]
CurveFit = 6;
PumpFit2[t_] = Fit[PickedPumpData2, Table[t^i, {i, 1, CurveFit}], t]
SimulatedPumpCurve2 = Plot[PumpFit2[t], {t, 0.735, 0.95}]
Solve[PumpFit2[t] == 0, t]
Pumpcurve2[t_] := 
 If[t > 0.9477938759997302` || t < 0.73786902921016`, 0, PumpFit2[t]]

PickedPumpData3 = Take[PumpData, {300, 340}];(*Data Pickup*)
RealPumpCurve3 = ListPlot[PickedPumpData3, PlotRange -> All]
CurveFit = 6;
PumpFit3[t_] = Fit[PickedPumpData3, Table[t^i, {i, 1, CurveFit}], t]
SimulatedPumpCurve3 = Plot[PumpFit3[t], {t, 1.5, 1.7}]
Solve[PumpFit3[t] == 0, t]
Pumpcurve3[t_] := 
 If[t > 1.6922549659684891` || t < 1.4993056416906838`, 0, 
  PumpFit3[t]]

WholePumpCurve[t_] := Pumpcurve1[t] + Pumpcurve2[t] + Pumpcurve3[t]
SimuWholePumpCurve = Plot[WholePumpCurve[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

The following code is how the fitted function used in the NDSolve:

```
NrmlPumpFit[t] = A WholePumpCurve[t];
NSolve[Integrate[NrmlPumpFit[t], {t, 0, 2}] == PulseEnergy, A]
A = 18.994202212484236`;
Nrmlpower = NrmlPumpFit[t]
Nrmlphoton = NrmlPumpFit[t]/(PlanckConst LightSpeed/(Wavelength))

OpticCoupl = 0.01;
optcrosection = 4 10^-17 (*cm^2*);
CrystalSize = 0.04189;
d = 0.3;
Ktot = 1/(9 10^-9)/10^3;
Kisc = 0.625 Ktot /10^3;
Krad = 0.375 Ktot/10^3;
refrindex = 1.61; 
Blight  = 3.87 10^21/10^3;;
ffactor = 0.5;
beamarea = Pi (1 10^-3)^2;
Wstimulatedemission = Nrmlpower 1.16 10;
w = 2 Pi 1.45 10^9;
q0 = 4277;
qthermal = 4277;
B = 9 10^-8 /10^3;
Kx = 2.7 10^4 /10^3;
Ky = 0.6 10^4 /10^3;
Kz = 1.7 10^3 /10^3;
Wxz = 1.1 10^4 /10^3;
Wyz = 2.2 10^4 /10^3;
Wxy = 0.44 10^4 /10^3;
Px = 0.76;
Py = 0.16;
Pz = 0.08;
Q0 = 7 10^3;
Qe = 7 10^3;
reciprocalQmprefactor = 7.26351*10^-19;

sol = NDSolve[{S0'[
     t] == -(Wstimulatedemission + Nrmlphoton) OpticCoupl (1 - 
        Exp[-S0[t] optcrosection d/CrystalSize]) + (Krad + 
        Wstimulatedemission OpticCoupl) S1[t] + Kx X[t] + Ky Y[t] + 
     Kz Z[t], 
   S1'[t] == (Wstimulatedemission + Nrmlphoton) OpticCoupl (1 - 
        Exp[-S0[t] optcrosection d/CrystalSize]) - (Krad + 
        Wstimulatedemission OpticCoupl) S1[t] - Kisc S1[t], 
   X'[t] == 
    Kisc S1[t]  Px - X[t] Kx - (X[t] - Z[t]) Wxz - (X[t] - Y[t]) Wxy -
      B (X[t] - Z[t]) q[t], 
   Y'[t] == 
    Kisc S1[t] Py - Y[t] Ky - (Y[t] - Z[t]) Wyz - (Y[t] - X[t]) Wxy, 
   Z'[t] == 
    Kisc S1[t] Pz - Z[t] Kz + (X[t] - Z[t]) Wxz + (Y[t] - Z[t]) Wyz + 
     B (X[t] - Z[t]) q[t], 
   q'[t] == -(w (1/Q0 + 1/Qe - 
           reciprocalQmprefactor (X[t] - Z[t]))) 10^-3 (q[t] - 
        qthermal) + B (X[t] - Z[t]) q[t], q[0] == q0, 
   X[0] == Y[0] == Z[0] == S1[0] == 0, S0[0] == Ns}, {X, Y, Z, q, S0, 
   S1}, {t, 0, 3}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not construct an interpolation function?  Also, it would be helpful if you showed the *Mathematica* code you used.

Comment: @JimB, Hi, thanks a lot for your reply! I have added the Mathematica code. May I ask can the interpolation function used in the NDSolve part?

Comment: I don't know if using `Interpolation` will work with `NDSolve`.  However your dataset on DropBox has 902 data points and from the recently added code only the first 340 points are to be used.  But in those 340 data points there are 68 times with the same first coordinate.  `Interpolation` only works with unique first coordinates.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for pointing out the duplication of the coordinates. I will correct it and try to see if I can use ```Interpolation``` for NDSolve.